# How can I update the index of a Multiview with Javascript in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I am trying to create a ASP:Multiview which contains 3 views.

I want to change the index value using Java script, because if I make any ASP:Button then it will refresh my page, so I don't want to refresh my page and change the Multiview's index value.
 thanks But I want it in javascript, Because when i click at that time it will be change, My button is input type= button so please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, when active view index is changed, then a new panel should also be displayed. So you could probably acheive the same using AJAX. With AJAX, your entire page will not refresh. Since, you are using ASP.NET 2.0. You can use AJAX toolkit.


[Here](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/) is a list of things you can achieve using AJAX.